# Watchman: where is the default log file?

Tags: build, build-process

Where does the build tool [watchman](https://facebook.github.io/watchman/) store it's log file by default?

Comment: The fastest way to determine the logfile location for a running watchman server is `ps ax | grep watchman` This displays the location of the logfile and statefile.

Comment: @NoahSussman make that an answer! The currently accepted answer doesn't work (for me), but yours did.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Check curent log file by default:

```
ps aux | grep watchman
```

mac          77620   0.0  0.0  2475836    672   ??  S<    2:26PM   0:00.23 /usr/local/Cellar/watchman/4.7.0/libexec/bin/watchman --foreground --`logfile`=/usr/local/var/run/watchman/mac-state/log --log-level=1 --`sockname`=/usr/local/var/run/watchman/mac-state/sock --`statefile`=/usr/local/var/run/watchman/mac-state/state --`pidfile`=/usr/local/var/run/watchman/mac-state/pid

Also, you are allowed to set your own log file.

```
watchman -o /tmp/log
```

see more:

```
watchman --help
```

-o, --logfile=PATH         Specify path to logfile

Answer (score 5):

> Watchman places logs in a file named `<STATEDIR>/<USER>.log`, where `STATEDIR` is set at the time that you built watchman.

By default, `STATEDIR` is `<PREFIX>/var/run/watchman/<USER>-state/log`.

> If you're running a homebrew build of watchman, you'll find the logs in a path named something like `/usr/local/Cellar/watchman/3.2.0/var/run/watchman/<USER>.log`.

Info taken from the docs at https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/troubleshooting.html#where-are-the-logs

Comment: That path is no longer correct (and is different depending on platform, config, etc). But the link is still helpful.

Comment: Updated with new info, should be better now.

Comment: What is `<PREFIX>`? The docs refer to it many times, and never explain what it refers to.

Comment: It's been a while since I used this, but I think it refers to the installation path prefix.  So in the above example, it's `usr/local/Cellar/watchman/3.2.0/`

Comment: @Joe: I think now, that path no longer exist? I can see upto this only: "/usr/local/Cellar/watchman/4.7.0_1"